# Chaincode installation on peer in HyperLedger Fabric

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to test my chaincode locally, for this I have a script to run, but whilst installation of chaincode(code below) getting error that chaincode path does not exists?

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p ./bitbucket.org/Foldername/testBlockchain/folder_name_for_chaincode
```

in all of the examples I have seen following command is used

```
peer chaincode -n mycc -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02
```

My question precisely is that how can I correct my path to point to chaincode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your chaincode available in the GOPATH, then you should be able to install it. Just either add your bitbucket folder into GOPATH or move you chaincode into `$GOPATH/src`.

**Update**

The following command

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p ./bitbucket.org/Foldername/testBlockchain/folder_name_for_chaincode
```

need to be replaced with

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p bitbucket.org/Foldername/testBlockchain/folder_name_for_chaincode
```

Comment: So you do not need the ‘./‘ as a path prefix

Answer (score 1):

```
Step a)
get the channel name using the following

peer channel list

step b)
get the chaincode version using this 

peer chaincode list --installed
```

[image]

```
step c)
install the chaincode using this

CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051 peer chaincode install -n mycc -p github.com/lc/go -v v3 


-n=name,
-v=version,
-p=path
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. My chain code is already in $GOPATH. Directory structure is as follows. Directory structure is as follows

```
$GOPATH                                                                                                              ->src       
    --->bitbucket.org
    ------>FolderName
    --------->chaincodefolder
    ------------->chaincodenamefolder
    ----------------chaincode.go
    ---------->Middleware
    ---------->localfabricfolder
```

Comment: my .sh file is in localfabricfolder and I am trying to access chaincode in chaincodefolder